# extra fields in views module

Tags: 7, views

I am using hook_form_alter to add few extra fields in a node. I have also managed to expose those fields in user interface using hook_field_extra_fields. All good until now but I can not see those exposed fields in views module? any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

In order to expose your field to Views, you need to implement Views API:

http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/api

This can be made much easier if you implement your field as a proper field, rather than a form alter. The [Examples project](http://drupal.org/project/examples) has some examples, notably [Field Permission Example](http://drupalcode.org/project/examples.git/tree/HEAD:/field_permission_example).